# kubeflow new notebook fails with "failed calling webhook"

Tags: ubuntu, kubeflow

I installed kubeflow on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS using [this guide](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/quickstart). After installation, in the dashboard I try and start a new notebook server which leads to the following error - see image below [image: dashboard screenshot]. Could anyone advise on a fix?

Comment: Is this being deployed to a private cluster? I've deployed kubeflow a few times to a private cluster and encountered a requirement for Istio to modify the firewall rules. See this [doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/). That resolved most of the errors within my kubeflow cluster, but I was still seeing a similar issue; `failed to call webhook: Post "https://admission-webhook-service.kubeflow.svc:443`. Maybe you need a firewall rule for port 4443 in your cluster? Were you able to fix this?